# Can MySQL update concurrent a table with different rows

Tags: mysql, database, performance, concurrency, query-optimization

I have a table (users) with 20M records.
I need to update column **user_image** (this is indexed colum) to a new value.
Now, I am using PHP + amphp/amp (https://github.com/amphp/amp) to run multiple threads.

After running my PHP script, it init multiple threads (10 threads)
and run parallel 10 Sql queries looks like below but different **id** (we can check by `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;`)

```
UPDATE `users` 
SET 
`user_image` = CASE
    WHEN id = '13404174' THEN 'b5035bf8-301d-4f46-8647-2354982e06f7.jpg'
WHEN id = '13404175' THEN '353a37cf-8e71-4233-9f6d-bffec270f3a6.jpg'
ELSE `user_image`
END
WHERE id in (13404174,13404175)

Note: ENGINE=InnoDB + Update 500 cases for each query
```

**Problem:**
I thought if running with 10 threads then it was 7-10x faster but from my testing, it is almost the same time when I run with 1 thread.

From my investigation: it seems MySQL **UPDATE** query is not running concurrently. One Update query takes 1s, then running 10 queries parallel takes ~10s to finish all of them

Could you please advise?

- Why it is not faster when I run with 10 threads?
- Do we have any way to migrate 20M records fastest?

Comment: Possibly related: [What's the most efficient way to batch UPDATE queries in MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/28282)

Comment: How many cases are there per query? If it's 2 (or less than 50ish) as in the example here, the concurrency overhead may be canceling out any potential gains. It doesn't look like MySQL would do a table lock for this query.

Comment: I updated 500 cases for each query

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN UPDATE ...` with 500 ids.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, here is my explaination
{
"EXPLAIN UPDATE xxx: [
 {
  "id" : 1,
  "select_type" : "SIMPLE",
  "table" : "users",
  "type" : "range",
  "possible_keys" : "PRIMARY",
  "key" : "PRIMARY",
  "key_len" : "4",
  "ref" : null,
  "rows" : "500",
  "Extra" : "Using where"
 }
]}

Comment: For now, I drop the index then update -> re-add index.
it is super fast, faster 10x.

Comment: Drop/add index alo does not lock our table